# in a same contract sending ether to two difffrent address

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

I have to write a smart contract in which participants has to sender ether to 2 different address I am not able to get that code .

Comment: Can you expand your question, maybe a use case or the code you have so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.